# Elasticache Redis connection time out in load but limits not exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm conducting load testing on a PHP/Laravel app hosted on Lambda with an RDS database and Elasticache Redis cache and session storage.

I've have removed any bottlenecks to do with the DB and Lambda by upping the relevant instance sizes and limits and now are running in to a redis/elasticache bottleneck we can't really understand.

When we reach a certain number of virtual users hitting our app, we run in to the below issue. "Connection timed out to the cache host."

[image: Connection timed out to the cache host.]

However as you can see in the below cloudwatch dashboard, the Elasticache metrics for CPU usage, connections, and network allowances do not appear to have any issue.

[image: Dashboard of cloudwatch metrics]

Upping the Elasticache instance appears to have some impact in that it allows a little bit more traffic but not too much. The main issue is we are unable to see from the metrics what is causing the connection time out when under load.